# Concatenate two tables with union

Tags: postgresql

Concatenate two tables in PostgreSQL version 9.5.1 with `UNION`; and check if the value in column `name` appears in one or both of these tables with a Boolean.

Here is my minimal example code:

```
WITH things_a(name) AS (
            VALUES ('AAA'),('BBB'),('CCC')),
     things_b(name) AS (
            VALUES ('BBB'),('CCC'),('DDD'))
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT name AS name,
      TRUE AS in_a,
          NULL::boolean AS in_b
   FROM things_a
   UNION SELECT name AS name,
        NULL AS in_a,
        TRUE AS in_b
   FROM things_b) AS things
ORDER BY name
```

For which I would like to have the following outcome:

```
name   | in_a    | in_b
------------------------
AAA    | t       | f
BBB    | t       | t
CCC    | t       | t
DDD    | f       | t
```

But there might be an alternative approach of course

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what results are you getting that are different from the goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want to use `UNION`?

You could simply use:

```
WITH things_a(name) AS (
            VALUES ('AAA'),('BBB'),('CCC')),
     things_b(name) AS (
            VALUES ('BBB'),('CCC'),('DDD'))
SELECT COALESCE(things_a.name,things_b.name) as name,
       things_a.name is not null as in_a, 
       things_b.name is not null as in_b
from things_a full outer join things_b 
     on things_a.name=things_b.name
order by 1
;
```

Or is your implied question asking for the missing parts of your sample code?

Then the following might be what you are looking for:

```
WITH things_a(name) AS (
            VALUES ('AAA'),('BBB'),('CCC')),
     things_b(name) AS (
            VALUES ('BBB'),('CCC'),('DDD'))
SELECT name, COALESCE(bool_or(in_a),false) as in_a, coalesce(bool_or(in_b),false) in_b
FROM
  (SELECT name AS name,
      TRUE AS in_a,
          NULL::boolean AS in_b
   FROM things_a
   UNION SELECT name AS name,
        NULL AS in_a,
        TRUE AS in_b
   FROM things_b) AS things
group by name
ORDER BY name;
```